# PHP parse XML subchild with same name and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing, insert

I can't insert into MySQL pictures listed in the XML as subchilds and with the same name.

I want to include it in the same field by commas.

Here is the structure of the XML file:

```
<item>
<title>product1</title>
<brand>Topcom</brand>
<product-code>14829</product-code>
<productcode>14829</productcode>
<barcode>5411519017314</barcode>
<available>1</available>
<price>179</price>
<price-promotional>149</price-promotional>
<images><img src="http://www.blabla.com/data_files/product_photos/9599/large.jpg"  height="1000"  width="1000" />
<img src="http://www.blabla.com/data_files/product_photos/9599/large_1.jpg"  height="1000"  width="1000" />
<img src="http://www.blabla.com/data_files/product_photos/9599/large_2.jpg"  height="1000"  width="1000" />
<img src="http://www.blabla.com/data_files/product_photos/9599/large_3.jpg"  height="1000"  width="1000" />
</images>
</item>
```

Mysql table schema is

```
$create1=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_stock` (
`title` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`manufacturer` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`img` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
`productcode` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`stock` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`active` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL)");
```

My PHP

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $product)
{
$sql1=mysql_query("insert into new_stock (title,manufacturer,img,productcode,price, active) values('$product->title','$product->brand','$product->images->img['src']','$product->productcode','$product->price','$product->available')");
}
```

Hopefully I share with you all the details.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "I want to include it in the same field by commas." That's not a good idea. Normalize your database. Anytime you're putting more than one thing into a single value you're making life difficult for yourself.

Comment: Hi Cris. Probably you have right...☺. How to do it?

Comment: That's pretty broad for Stack Overflow, Alex. And you haven't shared any information about your current database schema. Google "SQL many-to-one relationships" and go from there. If you hit any specific problems, feel free to come back and ask about them.